# AngularJs and HTML history

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have the following routes:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            controller  : 'ApplicationController',
            controllerAs : 'controller',
            templateUrl : 'includes/home/home.html',
        })
        // route for the about page
        .when('/Enterprise', {
            templateUrl : 'includes/enterprises/home_enterprise.html',
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});

    // use the HTML5 History API
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

My link :

```
<li><a ng-click="controller.MoveToCompanyHome(1)"><i class="fa fa-home">My Link</i></a></li>
```

I also have this line in my header :

```
<base href="/admin2/" />
```

And my controller's function:

```
this.MoveToCompanyHome = function(id_company){
    $location.path('/Enterprise');
};
```

This works fine until I tried to go to the previous page using my browser history. It tries to load /Enterprise and it doesn't work (404). I understand that my page will only work if I load index.html (or /) but can't understand how my history will work.
I tried to read angularJs' documentation (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location ) but I wasn't able to make my history working.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working. Click back on the browser should load from cache. In the network tab is it trying to request  /Enterprise and then returning a 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a 404 because you need to make changes to the server because `/Enterprise` doesn't exist on the server. These changes will depend on what technology you are using to host the angular app.

Taken from the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#server-side):

> **HTML5 mode**
>
> Using this mode requires URL rewriting on server side, basically you
> have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application
> (e.g. index.html).

Comment: I use a mutualized server (on OVH),  I don't think I have a lot of options to configure it.

Do I need to add something like : RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule admin2 /admin2/index.html
?

Comment: Yeah use RewriteEngine RewriteRule in .htaccess file. Take a look at this: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I have so far only deployed to the root. I think it might be RewriteRule (.*) /admin2/index.html [L]